# How to see dart core library code (StringBuffer)?

Tags: dart

I just wondered how the StringBuffer's concrete code is look like.

But I can only find abstract method like this. Well...

Could you please let me know how to get to the concrete code ? Thanks!

```dart
// Copyright (c) 2011, the Dart project authors.  Please see the AUTHORS file
// for details. All rights reserved. Use of this source code is governed by a
// BSD-style license that can be found in the LICENSE file.

part of dart.core;

class StringBuffer implements StringSink {
  /// Creates a string buffer containing the provided [content].
  external StringBuffer([Object content = ""]);

  /// Returns the length of the content that has been accumulated so far.
  /// This is a constant-time operation.
  external int get length;

  /// Returns whether the buffer is empty. This is a constant-time operation.
  bool get isEmpty => length == 0;

  /// Returns whether the buffer is not empty. This is a constant-time
  /// operation.
  bool get isNotEmpty => !isEmpty;

  /// Adds the string representation of [object] to the buffer.
  external void write(Object? object);

  /// Adds the string representation of [charCode] to the buffer.
  ///
  /// Equivalent to `write(String.fromCharCode(charCode))`.
  external void writeCharCode(int charCode);

  /// Writes all [objects] separated by [separator].
  ///
  /// Writes each individual object in [objects] in iteration order,
  /// and writes [separator] between any two objects.
  external void writeAll(Iterable<dynamic> objects, [String separator = ""]);

  external void writeln([Object? obj = ""]);

  /// Clears the string buffer.
  external void clear();

  /// Returns the contents of buffer as a single string.
  external String toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what target platform you are interested in which is also the reason why the do this since the `external` function can point to different implementation depending on target.

The implementation for the different platforms can be found here:
https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/tree/2.18.1/sdk/lib/_internal

So if you want to see the implementation used when running the Dart VM or compiled to AOT binary, the implementation of `StringBuffer` can be found here:
https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/2.18.1/sdk/lib/_internal/vm/lib/string_buffer_patch.dart

Another point here is that Dart VM code often have stuff like the following which you can see in the bottom of the `StringBuffer` implementation:

```dart
  @pragma("vm:external-name", "StringBuffer_createStringFromUint16Array")
  external static String _create(Uint16List buffer, int length, bool isLatin1);
```

This means that we do a call to the C++ code in the Dart runtime (which is bundled together with your compiled app). So the `_create` call will end up calling the following method:
https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/2.18.1/runtime/lib/string.cc#L516-L534

If your target are instead JavaScript, the code used for that implementation (when compiled to a release ready JS bundle) can be found here:
https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/2.18.1/sdk/lib/_internal/js_runtime/lib/core_patch.dart#L632